# Java PreparedStatement Delete Query: Show Number of Rows Deleted?

Tags: java, mysql, database, prepared-statement

I have a PreparedStatement with a MySQL query that deletes rows based on a timestamp criteria.  Is it possible to pull out how many rows were deleted from that same delete prepared statement or would I have to run a separate query to get the number first?  This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(delete, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        pstmt.setString(1, keyword);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            n = rs.getInt(1);
        } 
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
```

Sorry guys, I figured it out. int n = pstmt.executeUpdate();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it would be trusting in the result of [`PreparedStatement#executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29):

> **Returns** either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Another way could be using a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement before executing the delete statement. Note that you can do both in a single connection/transaction in order to not affect the results.